# Token invalid on reset password with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, identity, reset-password

I am trying to add the reset password functionality in my mvc web application.

When I enter my e-mail address and submit the form I receive the e-mail that contains the token etc, then when I click on the link I got redirected to the reset password page, there I enter my e-mail and the new password, then when I hit reset button I got the following error from the resetPassword action:

**"invalid token".**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            // Don't reveal that the user does not exist
            return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }

        var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
        return View();
    }
```

And my ForgotPassword Method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)

    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
            }

            string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

            var emailTemplateQuery = await _emailTemplateService.Query(x => x.Slug.ToLower() == "forgotpassword").SelectAsync();
            var emailTemplate = emailTemplateQuery.Single();

            dynamic email = new Postal.Email("Email");
            email.To = user.Email;
            email.From = CacheHelper.Settings.EmailAddress;
            email.Subject = emailTemplate.Subject;
            email.Body = emailTemplate.Body;
            email.CallbackUrl = callbackUrl;
            EmailHelper.SendEmail(email);

            return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }
```

ForgotPassword.cshtml file:

```
            <div class="panel-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotPassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <h4>[[[Enter your email.]]]</h4>
                    <hr /> 
                     @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="[[[Email Link]]]" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
```

ForgotPasswordConfirmation.cshtml file:

```
            <div class="panel-body">                    
                <div>
                    <p>
                        [[[Please check your email to reset your password.]]]
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

ResetPasswordViewModel:

```
public class ResetPasswordViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "[[[Email]]]")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "[[[The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.]]]", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "[[[Password]]]")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "[[[Confirm password]]]")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "[[[The password and confirmation password do not match.]]]")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your view model + full error log ?

Comment: is it asp.net MVC 5?

Comment: Yes, it is Mvc 5

Comment: you should add code of ForgotPasswordConfirmation action and ForgotPassword view and model also.

Comment: Could you show us your ResetPasswordViewModel and the full error log ?

Comment: Hi Antonie, i added ResetPasswordViewModel. But i don't know full error log. How do i find ?

Comment: have you got @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in your reset password form?

Comment: Yes, there is @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in my ResetPassword.cshtml file.

Comment: What you can do first is execute your program in debug mode and put breakpoints in your ResetPassword POST method. Then check if your ResetPasswordViewModel is fully populated with the correct data. 
You'll be able to determine exactly where is your problem.

Comment: My problem;
Line: var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
Problem: model.code is null

Comment: I see that your `RouteParam` on this line : 
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

Doesn't match the parameters on the method ResetPassword, your problem might come from the parameters binding. In order to have the parameters binded, the names must match. Or do you have a GET method that you didn't showed us yet ?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help.I have added the following code and i solved the problem.

ResetPassword Method:

```
string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, code, model.Password);
```

Comment: I think this wont solve your issue, you're generating a token just before reseting the password and you're not using the one you sent by mail.
It works yes, but it's a security issue in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But, if i don't have the code, i can't enter the reset password page. Even so, i know it's not safe. Else, how do I solve it?

Comment: I actually just ended up using this solution too... bumped my head for days and have no other option...